# multi selectors in socket programming in python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm a newbie in programming python, can I using multi secletor in programing socket ? . If could, please give me a example. Thanks everyone so much!

Comment: What does "multi selectors" or "multi secletor" mean? Please elaborate.

Comment: In Java, I found that we can use multiple selectors to program socket in non-blocking mode,so I wonder this is available in Python ?.

Comment: Again: what are "selectors"? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

See the [official Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#non-blocking-sockets) for the basics of asynchronous I/O with non-blocking sockets.

See [PyMOTW](http://pymotw.com/2/select/) for a good tutorial on the `select` module, with its `select.select()` function.

Other tutorials can be found at [IBM developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-pysocks/section4.html) and at [BGU](http://ilab.cs.byu.edu/python/select/echoserver.html).

On Unix/Linux, `select.poll()` and `select.epoll()` are similar in concept to `select.select()` but much more efficient.